# Please explain why error: no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector occurs while coverting an ESRI .shp to matrix for SVM training data?

Tags: r, matrix, svm

I want to convert a pre-loaded shapefile into matrix, but I'm getting following error while running the codes:

```
matrix1 <- as.matrix(trainData)

Error in as.vector(data) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Please suggest solution!